# decode 3Des with 64bit encoded text

Tags: java, encryption, 3des, java-security

if we have a encoded text using 3Des with 64bit encoding, is it enough to have the encryption key? What else info we need.

I tried and im hitting below error.

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Comment: Sorry, i was referring to get back the original text from encrypted code. currently I have the encrypted code and the key. As an info given me that they used  '3Des with 64bit encoding'

Comment: Presumably you mean encrypted, 3DES (triple DES) and a 64-bit key which neither DES not 3DES has.

Comment: its BASE64 encoding  with TripleDES @zaph

Comment: See [3DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES).

Answer (score 1):

1. DES, 3DES and AES among others are block cyphers meaning that they must have input data that is an exact multiple of the block size (8-bytes in DES). Either ensure data is **always** a multiple of blocksize or use padding, PKCS#5 to add and remove padding bytes to achieve the block multiple requirement.
2. Do not use 3DES, it has been superseded by AES is is not sufficiently secure for new work.
3. 3DES is a 168-bit key (24-bytes), sometimes for compatibility a 112-bit key (16-bytes) is used. Initially the bytes were parity checked with only 7-bits for data in each byte, the parity check is generally no longer done but still only the lower 7-bits per byte are used.
4. It is always best to supply a key of exact size.
5. You should use AES in CBC mode with a random IV.
6. If you are using a string key, possibly user supplied) you should derive  correct length key by using PBKDF2.
7. A message authentication MAC is also a good idea.

Comment: Hi zaph, Thanks alot for the reply. Actually this is some old data i need to decrypt and use for my app. So I have no options of changing it :)   

Yes, i have read some about this technology. But facing an error while decrypting. do u have any idea about this ?  


Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)

Comment: Note point 1 in the answer. You need to know exactly how the data was encrypted. But since security is not a concern just get it decrypted, just like the bridge designer using faulty design methods.

Comment: The info given is  'encrypted with 3Des + 64bit encoding' and the key used. :) Im lacking padding mechanism they used?

Comment: You are also missing: 1. The mode such as ECB, CBC, CTR, etc. 2. Possible IV. 3. How you use a 64-bit key with 3DES which expects a 168-bit (24-byte) key.

Comment: Triple DES (3DES) works also with 56 bit keys (with 8 parity bits) when all the subkeys are the same. There are also different combinations of keys such as K1-K1-K1 (56 bit), K1-K2-K1 (112 bit), K1-K2-K3 (168 bit). Additionally, all those combinations can be either executed with 3 times Encrypt (EEE) or Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt (EDE). K1-K1-K2 with EDE would also be possible.